# SUPEE-11155 for magento 1.9.3.10

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-11155

I don't see the patch SUPEE-11155 for Magento version 1.9.3.10 in the Magento site https://cl.ly/c96fd50d706d . Is this patch not needed for 1.9.3.10? 
I tried to install for version 1.9.3.9 and 1.9.4.0 but I faced some issues. I was wondering: If I should go and fix the errors, apply the patch manually from files not bash, or should not apply it?

Answer (score 1):

Needed. Fix the errors. Manual patch.

Looks like they've missed it.

Definitely not included.

1.9.3.10  - Added Sep 18, 2018

Includes patches: SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-5994, SUPEE-6237, SUPEE-6285, SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-7616, SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-7405 v1.1, SUPEE-8788, SUPEE-9652, SUPEE-8167, SUPEE-9767v2, SUPEE-10266, SUPEE-10415, SUPEE-10570, SUPEE-10752, SUPEE-10888

Comment: should i use the version 1.9.4.0 ?

Comment: Easier to patch than update.  But up to you.

Comment: Sorry, what i meant is should i use the version of patch for 1.9.4.0